# Preparatory text/s for Boas' Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences?

Tags: textbooks

Assuming that I remember only basic arithmetic, what (if any) mathematics must I learn before tackling Boas' *[Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471198269)*?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to work your way through high school algebra (typically, 2 years of coverage, such as the two Mary P. Dolciani texts [**Algebra, Book 1**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0395142555) and [**Algebra, Book 2**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000J4LEJS)) and precalculus (another year of coverage, such as Mary P. Dolciani's [**Modern Introductory Analysis**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0395286972)), then a standard 3-semester calculus text (diff. calculus, integral calculus, multivariable calculus -- such as Thomas/Finney's [**Calculus and Analytic Geometry**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201531747)). That might be minimally enough, but better would be to also cover a one-semester course in ordinary differential equations (such as Abell/Braselton's [**Introductory Differential Equations**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0124172199)) and a one-semester course in elementary linear algebra (such as Howard Anton's [**Elementary Linear Algebra**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470559918)).

Comment: so no one text book then?